# How to detect that UITableView is in editing mode?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, didselectrowatindexpath

I have a situation in which I am putting the UITableView in editing mode, and when it is not in editing mode, it has to perform tableview: didSelectRowAtIndexPath: and has to be pushed on a UINAvigationController.

Now the problem is that how can I check that whether the UITableView is in editing mode so that it should not be pushed over UINavigationController.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> editing
>
> A Boolean value that determines whether the receiver is in
>   editing mode.
>
> @property(nonatomic, getter=isEditing) BOOL editing

i.e. `[tableView isEditing] == YES`

Answer (score 2):

There is a property `editing` on your tableView, check if it's YES or NO.

Answer (score 1):

check this

if (yourtableview.isEditing == YES)
  {
     //do something
  }